# How do I make the cursor hover over the whole button instead of text?

Tags: hover, navbar, navigationbar

I'm a beginner and just started coding.

I'm coding a navigationbar with one button that has a dropdown. The only problem is that I don't know why the cursor doesn't hover when it goes over the "container" where the text is at. It only hovers over the text.

I'm talking about the page/button "Breed info"

But the dropdown itself works fine.

I think it has something to do with the<a> , <button> elements.  Not sure how to fix it.

Yes , I know, I used a lot of w3schools content and modified a little bit. I also fixed the problem about the blue/underline of that page because I want that to be clickable as well.

Sorry for my english, grammar is not the best.

[Click to see the problem :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbASi.png)

```
.eraseblueline
```

HTML

```
 <ul >
    <div class="pullright">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a class="eraseblueline" href="breedinfo.html">Breed info</a></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Color/marking genes</a>
      <a href="#">Hairtypes</a>
      <a href="#">Mutations</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    
      
      <li><a href="world.html">World</a></li>
      <li><a href="masterlist.html">Masterlist</a></li>
      
    
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(0, 153, 255);
  
}

.pullright {
  float: right;
}

li {
 
  float:left;
 
}

li a {
  font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding:15px 58px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  
  
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #bbb599;
  
}

.ul a {
  
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
 
}
.dropdown{
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding:15px 58px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0; /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}

.ul a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color:#bbb599;
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #bbb599;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.eraseblueline {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  
}
```

I tried using display:block; on different elements. But nothing happened. I noticed that alle pages where the hover works has <li> elemnts in the <ul>.

This page has <button> element , i got it from w3schools so not sure if it's wrong to change that element.